# How do I group sum of variables in php that are closest to a value, but also unique

Tags: php, arrays, algorithm, math

Let's say I have an array (5,3,5,7,10)

the number desired is 12

So i want the first stack to be:

------------------------ first output --------

7+5 = 12 (the best combination with lower number of variables) - exclude 7 and 5, don't ever use it

------------ second output ------------

10 - because it's the second variable closest to 12. (then exclude 10, don't ever use it)

------------ third output ----------

5+3 = 8 - because it's the third closest to 12

I searched all the internet but i don't find a clue

THankyou

Comment: Wouldn't this effectively be doing the same thing as summing them all? Why does order matter?

Comment: Do you need three closest outputs or use all the values from the array? Can the sum be made from more than two numbers if it is the closest one?

Comment: what I mean, I want to find all the variables that are closer to a number. The variables are summed but they do not repeat.

Comment: to be more accurate, i have an array (2,3,55,32,43), i need the best combinations for variables that are closest to number 60 but they do not repeat

Answer (score 0):

This problem is a harder version of the [Subset Sum Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem)

The successive sub-problems are essentially the approximation version on a smaller subset.  Solving this problem for large arrays exactly will be brutally slow.